# Transforming TM75(29903) squares to ETRS89(3035)?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, shapely

A bit of a long winded explanation here so please bear with me. I have received grid square data in ETRS89(3035) which I need to cross reference with out own grid squares which are in TM75(29903). However I am having issues with the transformation. I have created some images in QGIS to demonstrate.

The following shows a 10km fishnet created in 3035 bounding Ireland. The pink squares are the 3035 data which I received.

[image]

However if I simply re-project my 29903 squares to 3035 you end up with the following issue. You can see that the green squares are tilted. The layer is re-projected but since the squares were drawn using the parallel lines on 29903 they appear tilted in 3035. I realised the issue was likely the same as explained here [Projection Transformation from ETRS89 LAEA to WGS1984?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158720/projection-transformation-from-etrs89-laea-to-wgs1984). The re-projection is done but the squares need to be essentially redrawn in 3035.

[image]

I surmised that the best way to approach this would be to get the centroid of each of my 29903 squares, re-project that point to 3035 and then rebuild my 10km square buffer. I am using shapely to rebuild the buffer. This works..sort of. But as the following image shows the squares are essentially rotated individually and so are slightly out of position or overlapping.

[image]

At this point, the way forward which I am considering is iterating through my re-projected centroid points and finding the 3035 square from the 3035 fishnet which contains said centroid and then setting my updated geometry to that square. Does that seem like a valid approach?

The goal is to reproject my 29903 squares to 3035 and have them be on the same grid square scheme as the 3035 data which I need to cross reference. The same applies vice versa in fact. Included below is the script which I am testing to do the reprojection. Note I have not implemented my fishnet approach yet.

```
import ogr, osr
import os
from shapely.geometry import Point

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

# input SpatialReference
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(29903)

# output SpatialReference
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(3035)

# create the CoordinateTransformation
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# get the input layer
inDataSet = driver.Open(r'I:\Code\Python\input\test_shape\test_shape.shp')
inLayer = inDataSet.GetLayer()

# create the output layer
outputShapefile = r'I:\Code\Python\output\test_shape\test_shape.shp'
if os.path.exists(outputShapefile):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outputShapefile)
outDataSet = driver.CreateDataSource(outputShapefile)
outLayer = outDataSet.CreateLayer("basemap", outSpatialRef, geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon)

# add fields
inLayerDefn = inLayer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(0, inLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
    fieldDefn = inLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    outLayer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# get the output layer's feature definition
outLayerDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()

# loop through the input features
inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()
while inFeature:
    # get the input geometry
    geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
    print(geom.Centroid().GetX())
    centroid = geom.Centroid()
    centroid.Transform(coordTrans)
    geom = Point(centroid.GetX(), centroid.GetY())
    geom = geom.buffer(5000, cap_style=3)
    geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(geom.wkt)
    geom.AssignSpatialReference(outSpatialRef)
    print(geom.Centroid().GetX())

    # create a new feature
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(outLayerDefn)
    # set the geometry and attribute
    outFeature.SetGeometry(geom)
    for i in range(0, outLayerDefn.GetFieldCount()):
        outFeature.SetField(outLayerDefn.GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), inFeature.GetField(i))
    # add the feature to the shapefile
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
    # dereference the features and get the next input feature
    outFeature = None
    inFeature = inLayer.GetNextFeature()

# Save and close the shapefiles
inDataSet = None
outDataSet = None
```